# JavaScript Promise with Ajax call inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the essence of what I'm trying to do...

Creating a simple page that let's users submit a vacation request.  If the request if of type 'Leave of Absence', then a note is required.  So, if the request type is 'Leave of Absence', do an Ajax call to the server to get the note count for this request.  If it's zero, stop the process.  If it's > 0, then save the request.

I'm trying to do this with a promise, but I'm doing something wrong....

```
for (var i = 0; i < VacationRequests.length; i++)
{
    if (VacationRequests[i].VacationRequestType == leaveOfAbsenceType)
    {
        GetNoteCountPromise.then(function(result) {
            SaveVacationRequest(VacationRequests[i]);
        }, function(err) {
           $('#LeaveOfAbsenceModal').modal('show');
           return;
        });
    }
}
```

And here's the promise...

```
    var GetNoteCountPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNoteCount", "VacationRequests")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { VacationRequestId: vacationRequestId },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data > 0) {
                    resolve(true);
                }
                else {
                    reject(false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

First question:

I somehow need to pass `vacationRequestId` into the promise.  Not sure how to do that.

Second question:

Am I doing this right?

**EDIT:**

This what I did first:

```
for (var i = 0; i < VacationRequests.length; i++)
{
    if (VacationRequests[i].VacationRequestType == leaveOfAbsenceType)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNoteCount", "VacationRequests")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { VacationRequestId: vacationRequestId },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data > 0) {
                    SaveVacationRequest(VacationRequests[i]); /// THIS is where it broke down
                }
                else {
                    $('#LeaveOfAbsenceModal').modal('show');
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem with this, is that by the time we hit the Success method, the loop had finished and `VacationRequests[i]` was undefined.

Comment: either promise or ajax will be enough.Promise is used to remove these kind of nested ajax.

Comment: Ok... I get that. (well, maybe I don't?)  When I did it with ajax alone, I had problems.  I'll modify the OP.  brb.

Comment: Modified.  See OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem with this, is that by the time we hit the Success method, the loop had finished and VacationRequests[i] was undefined.

In order to solve this issue (refer to [closure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) you may use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

Another solution can be based on [javaScript let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

```js
var leaveOfAbsenceType = 1;
var VacationRequests = [{VacationRequestType: 1, VacationRequestId: 1}, {VacationRequestType: 1, VacationRequestId: 2}]
for (var i = 0; i < VacationRequests.length; i++)
{
    if (VacationRequests[i].VacationRequestType == leaveOfAbsenceType)
    {
        (function(i) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { VacationRequestId: VacationRequests[i].vacationRequestId },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('success -->' + i);
                },
                errror: function() {
                    console.log('errror -->' + i);
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be working!  Going to test a little more, but so far so good!

Comment: (Not sure who down voted you.  I voted it back up.  REALLY appreciate the help!)

Comment: Yes, this does look to be working!  Thank you! Can I ask you to explain to me what's going on here with the IIFE?  Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston the IIFE works because variables in javascript have a function scope. the trailing "(i)" basically says "invoke this function with this argument" and that value for i is then captured and preserved for inside that new function block.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that i is VacationRequests.length (so 1 greater than the highest index) by the time you hear back from the server. It's a frequent issue run into when you're just getting into async programming. To illustrate the problem:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i);
    }, 0);
}
```

You can fix this by leveraging an IIFE and scoping the variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < VacationRequests.length; i++)
{
    function scoping(i){
        if (VacationRequests[i].VacationRequestType == leaveOfAbsenceType)
        {
             var VacationRequestId = i;//or whatever the id is at this location
             GetNoteCountPromise(VacationRequestId).then(function(result) {
                SaveVacationRequest(VacationRequests[i]);
            }, function(err) {
               $('#LeaveOfAbsenceModal').modal('show');
               return;
            });
        }
    }(i)
}

var GetNoteCountPromise = function(vacationRequestId){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetNoteCount", "VacationRequests")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { VacationRequestId: vacationRequestId },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data > 0) {
                resolve(true);
            }
            else {
                reject(false);
            }
        }
    });
});
};
```

Also we can get the vacationRequestId into a closure to make it accessible to the promise.

Comment: thanks!  Testing this.

Comment: Hmm... Didn't work.  No errors in the console... just... nothing.  (Not sure who down voted you.  I voted it back up.  REALLY appreciate the help!)

Comment: @KevinB I fail to see how it has the SAME problem as the OP. Clearly I can't execute it, where is the problem? i should be scoped to the named "scoping" function